# How can i replace particular number of letters from particular position?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to replace a particular number of characters, for example 3 characters from the 4th position in a string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the `STUFF` function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx